# error in calculating small double number with C++

Tags: c++, qt, double

I am using C++/Qt to do calculation on small double number, and some strange thing happened. In the following code, the value for t_prob should be 1.62457e-12, but it was 3.24907e-12 (like 2 * 1.62457e-12).

Meanwhile, I have added a control with a, b, c, and d, and the result is correct.

Could you give me some suggestion about this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtMath>

#define PI 3.1415926536

double tprob(qint64 n, double x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 0.00000000000162448;
    double c = a - b;
    double d = 1.0 - c;

    qDebug() << "a:" << a;
    qDebug() << "b:" << b;
    qDebug() << "c:" << c;
    qDebug() << "d:" << d;

    double df = 127.793;
    double t_statistic = 9.77749;
    double ta = tprob(floor(df),-1.0 *t_statistic);
    double tb = tprob(floor(df), t_statistic);
    double t_prob = 1.0 - qAbs(ta - tb);

    qDebug() << "df:" << df;
    qDebug() << "t_statistic:" << t_statistic;
    qDebug() << "ta:" << ta;
    qDebug() << "tb:" << tb;
    qDebug() << "t_prob:" << t_prob;


    return 1;
}


double tprob(qint64 n, double x){
    if( n < 0 ){
    qDebug() << "[error] wrong n value input for tprob";
    exit(0);
    }

    double a,b,w,z,y,p;
    w=atan2(1.0 * x/sqrt(n),1);

    z=cos(w)*cos(w);
    y=1.0;
    p=0;

    for(qint64 i=n-2; i>=2;i-=2){
    y= 1 + 1.0 * (i-1)/i * z * y;
    }

    if( n%2 ==0){
    a=sin(w)/2;
    b=0.5;
    }else{
    a = (n==1)?0:sin(w)*cos(w)/PI;
    b = 0.5 + w/PI;
    }

    p = 1- b - a * y;

    if( p>0){
    return p;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
}
```

output:

```
a: 1.62448e-12
b: 1
c: 1
d: 1.62448e-12
df: 127.793
t_statistic: 9.77749
ta: 1
tb: 1.62457e-12
t_prob: 3.24907e-12
```

Comment: Could give more precision about what your program is doing? what are `df` and `t_statistic` variable?

Comment: Looks like floating point precision at work...http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b56ef29755bceb0

Comment: @Marcel This is part of a large project, and I want to do t-test in this section, and the completed formula is `t_prob = 1.0- qAbs (tprob(floor(df),-1.0 *t_statistic) - tprob(floor(df), t_statistic))` and `df` and `t_statistic` are used to calculate accumulated p value with the function `tprob`, which was successfully tested.

Comment: @Marcel  I have get correct value `ta = tprob(floor(df),-1.0 *t_statistic)` and `tb = tprob(floor(df), t_statistic)`. When I go on doing calculating with `ta` and `tb`, then something error happened. With a control(`a`, `b`, `c`,  and `d`), I assign the `ta` and `tb` value to `b` and `a` directly, and then the result is correct.

Comment: @SimonKraemer  I have get correct value `ta = tprob(floor(df),-1.0 *t_statistic)` and `tb = tprob(floor(df), t_statistic)`. When I go on doing calculating with `ta` and `tb`, then something error happened. With a control(`a`, `b`, `c`,  and `d`), I assign the `ta` and `tb` value to `b` and `a` directly, and then the result is correct.

Comment: @SimonKraemer:  you're calling the wrong `abs`. Since you don't `#include <cmath>`, you're getting the integer version in `stdlib.h`. If you use `fabs` (after including math.h or cmath), you'll get the right answer. Or include cmath and use `std::abs`.

Comment: @ybzhao: Please include a [mcve]. The snippet you have included is incomplete and therefore cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @rici The completed code was updated.

Comment: @Marcel The completed code was updated.

Comment: @SimonKraemer The completed code was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're printing the float values with `<<`, by default you only get 6 digits precisions or something.

Compare:

```
qDebug() << "c:" << c;
output: 1
```

With:

```
qDebug() << "c:" << QString("%1").arg(c, 0, 'g', 15);
output: "0.999999999998376"
```

So tprob = 1.0 - qAbs(ta - tb) = 1.0 - qAbs(1.0 - epsilon - epsilon) = 2*epsilon

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions to avoid this problem?

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem. Actually, the value for t_prob is correct.

Comment: Yes it is, it's just a misleading display.